# Change radius on mousemove kineticJS

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, kineticjs, mousemove

I want to create sort of a 3D effect with the shapes I generated with KineticJS on my canvas.
When I drag them to the top, the need to become smaller, and when dragged to the bottom, they need to become bigger.

The closest I got to what I wanted is with the mousemove event you see here

```
$.each(bubbles, function(){
var bubble = this;
bubble = new Kinetic.Circle({x:this.x, y:this.y, radius:this.r, fill:'#000000', draggable:true});
bubble.on("mousemove",function(){
    bubble.setRadius((bubble.getY()/5));
});
layer.add(bubble);

});
```

But this only changes the radius when ending dragging and click the shape again.

It would be very nice if I can make it possible to change them "realtime", when dragging.

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this?
Here's my JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ZsADd/1/

Thank you!

Comment: no bubbles in your fiddle? Maybe you should load your kinectic library into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is `bubble.on("dragmove")`.  [Here is an example of it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/ZsADd/5/).  For more info on drag events, look into the documentation which I found [here](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-drag-and-drop-events-tutorial/).

> To detect drag and drop events with KineticJS, we can use the `on()`
>   method to detect `dragstart` , `dragmove`, or `dragend` events. The `on()`
>   method requires an event type and a function to be executed when the
>   event occurs.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Now I feel stupid for looking over that in the documentation. Thanks Ivan!